# two different csv file data manipulation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I have two data frame df1 and df2

df1 has following data (N Rows)

```
  Time(s)   sv-01 sv-02 sv-03  Val1  val2  val3 
   1339.4   1     4      12     1.6   0.6   1.3
   1340.4   1     12     4     -0.5  0.5   1.4
   1341.4   1     6      8      0.4   5     1.6
   1342.4   2     5     14      1.2   3.9    11
   ......           .....      ....   ...    ..
```

df2 has following data which has more rows than df1

```
Time(msec)   channel  svid    value-1   value-2 valu-03
1000          1       2       0          5       1
1000          2       5       1          4       2
1000          3       2       3          4       7
.....         .....................................
1339400      1        1       1.6        0.4     5.3
1339400      2        12      0.5       1.8      -4.4
1339400      3        4       -0.20     1.6      -7.9
1340400      1        1      0.3       0.3      1.5
1340400      2        6      2.3      -4.3      1.0
1340400      3        4      2.0       1.1      -0.45
1341400      1       1       2         2.1      0
1341400      2       8       3.4      -0.3       1
1341400      3       6       0         4.1      2.3
....       ....      ..      ...        ...      ...
```

What I am trying to achieve is

1.first multiplying Time(s) column by 1000 so that it matches with df2
millisecond column.

2.In df1 sv 01,02 and 03 are in independent column but those sv are 
present in same column under svid.

So goal is when time of df1(after changing) is matching with time 
of df2 copy next three consecutive lines i.e copy all matched
lines of that time instant.

Basically I want to iterate the time of df1 in df2 time column
and if there is a match copy three next rows and copy to a new df.

I have seen examples using pandas merge function but in my case both have
different header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need double [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first `df2` with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), for multiple is used [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

And then count values per groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and filter first 3:

```
df = df2[df2['Time(msec)'].isin(df1['Time(s)'].mul(1000))]
df = df[df.groupby('Time(msec)').cumcount() < 3]
print (df)
    Time(msec)  channel  svid  value-1  value-2  valu-03
3      1339400        1     1      1.6      0.4     5.30
4      1339400        2    12      0.5      1.8    -4.40
5      1339400        3     4     -0.2      1.6    -7.90
6      1340400        1     1      0.3      0.3     1.50
7      1340400        2     6      2.3     -4.3     1.00
8      1340400        3     4      2.0      1.1    -0.45
9      1341400        1     1      2.0      2.1     0.00
10     1341400        2     8      3.4     -0.3     1.00
11     1341400        3     6      0.0      4.1     2.30
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('Time(msec)').cumcount())
3     0
4     1
5     2
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Poka - yes, no problem ;)

Comment: Can you check `df = df2[df2['Time(msec)'].isin(df1['Time(s)'].round(1).mul(1000).astype(int))]` ?

Comment: Hmm, then the best is convert column in `df1` to `ms` for match data and then use `df = pd.merge(df1, df, left_on='Time(s)', right_on='Time(msec)', how='right')`.

Comment: @ Jezrael. df2 has all time instant of df1. So'' df = df2[df2['Time(msec)'].isin(df1['Time(s)'].mul(1000))]'' shall give total number of df1 time instant but is outputting less than df1 number. It is jumping from 59 to 63 after some iteration  as shown  5455    32945600 
5457    32945800 
5459    32946000 
5463    32946400 . It is not taking 3294200 when both dataframe has this value

Comment: There is not problem with floats accuracy, so no match?

Comment: @ Jezrael. Manually I have compared. There is no problem with float. But it is missing some value. df = df2[df2['Time(msec)'].isin(df1['Time(s)'].mul(1000))] is skipping intermediate values. But do not know why.